# What are Barra style factors useful for?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, factor-models

I'm reading the paper's summary of:

> Beckers, Stan, and Jolly Ann Thomas. "On the persistence of style
>   returns." The Journal of Portfolio Management 37.1 (2010): 15-30.

about how some of these 'Barra style factors' create significant risk premiums, but I don't understand what they are and how a strategy can use them.

The full article is paywalled, but hopefully [this](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/247906339_On_the_Persistence_of_Style_Returns) gives an idea of the context.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mobius and welcome to quant.SE! can you edit the question adding the reference with a link to the paper, please?

Comment: @Quantopic, added above

Comment: I edited the question adding the complete reference. In such way, if someone have read that, can help you more likely @mobius.

Answer (score 4):

Style factors are used to describe the risk or returns of a portfolio or a asset. Style factors describe them in consistent terms that a board of directors or a portfolio manager can understand. You cannot easily do this with eigen values for example.

```
"... Identify segments of the market  with distinguishable patterns of returns."
```

The first known style factor was the value factor, described in Ben Ghrams 1934 Securities Analysis.

They are used the same as other factors and this question has been [answered before on the site.](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factor-models)

Comment: +1 for Ghrams' factor! I did not know that :)

Answer (score 3):

Barra risk factors are particular factors used to implement the Barra risk factor analysis, that consists in a multi-factor model developed by Barra inc. to measure the overall risk to which a financial asset is exposed.

According to [investopedia.com](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/barra-risk-factor-analysis.asp):

> Barra Risk Factor Analysis incorporates over **40 data metrics**
>   including: earnings growth, share turnover and senior debt rating. The
>   model then measures risk factors associated with three main
>   components: industry risk, risk from exposure to different investment
>   themes and company-specific risk.

Finally, Barra risk factors do not differ from common risk factors used by other practioners or academics from a theoretical point of view, but, rather, are a synthesis of them and of the asset risk.

I suggest to read the last release of [MSCI/Barra methodology](https://www.msci.com/eqb/methodology/meth_docs/MSCI_Barra_Factor%20Indices_Methodology_Nov13.pdf), in which MSCI explains which are the factors used and how they construct them to get a clear idea about such risk factors.